# How to predict the object location in the near future?

Tags: python, c++, future, prediction, kalman-filter

Assume that every object (car, bike etc.) is connected to internet and giving me (Cloud) just its current position and its random id, which is changes every “T” sec. Since objects changes their id’s it becomes difficult to keep track of every object, especially in a busy area like city center. Can someone help me to design an attacker model, which can predict the trajectories of the objects. That means the Cloud has to predict the direction of the objects in next, say 15 min.

You can assume like 4 regions A,B,C,D (5-10km of radius each) which are close to each other. How can I (cloud) predict and say, so many number cars/bikes have moved from Region A to Region B or the objects which I have seen in Region A and after 15min in Region B are the same.[image: Better explanation]

I have studied through Kalman filter. In my case I know only Random Id and positions. So First step could be guessing the velocity of each object from 2 consecutive position points, then forming velocity vector and position vector. Then applying position vector and velocity vector to Kalman filter. Somehow predicting the positions of objects in next 15 min. Ofcouse, need not be accurate atleast probable near by region.

Is kalman filter right choice? If so any python or c++ implementation that can help? Is there any other concept which can help in predicting the user locations? Is there any simulator that can help in simulating these networks? Can someone please help in designing this attacker model? Thanks a lot.

Edit1:
Main idea behind chaning the Object Id's is to protect the user(object location) privacy. My challenge is design an attacker model, where I can prove even though you(object) changed your Id's but I can still track you based on the speed, direction you are going. Let's say a car is going on a highway. It's id (assume 1234) at 12:00. At 12:15 it has changed its Id to 2345. since no one is going in the same direction,with that particular speed. The attacker can say Id:2345 and Id:1234 are from the same object. So This is a valid linkability. But if the same object is moving in busy area, like city center. I have many combinations like turns, parking lots(where many objects report same location with different Id's) it's difficult to say Id:2345 is from the same object Id:1234.

MainGoal:
If I can find the valid linkability of objects seen in Regions A (say at 12:00Pm) and in region B (say at 12:15) .That means I need to predict the Region B where the users(most of the objects) are trying to move. ofcouse some times It might be falsepositive. Since main goal is to protect user privacy, the false positive helps the users.

Comment: Why can't you just estimate a transition matrix for the Markov chain containing a state for each of your regions?

Comment: If you don't mind. Can you please point me to an worked example, How to determine transition matrix for Markov chain for my purpose(moving objects). Upon googling it has resulted me lot of theoritical tutorials. I am not understanding, how to determine transition matrix. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample dataset? Is Python OK?

Comment: @D3C34C34D I am using this [data set](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/b16d359d-d164-469e-9fd4-daa38f2b2e13/). Yes is python is okay. Thank you so much.

Comment: This is a bit more complicated than I originally thought. Have a look at https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~brill/Papers/spatialtrajectories.pdf and see if you can find an analog to your problem.

Answer (score 3):

> Is kalman filter right choice?

- A Kalman filter won't help in cases where the future predicted position depends on whether the vehicle makes a turn.  A [Markov model](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~aarti/Class/10701_Spring14/slides/HMM.pdf) may work better for those cases.
- On a straight-away with no turns, a Kalman filter will do better.  However, Kalman filters assume a gaussian (normal) distribution for noise (which likely is only true when the vehicle has no surrounding traffic).
- An [Unscented Kalman filter](https://cse.sc.edu/~terejanu/files/tutorialUKF.pdf) can help compensate for the non-guassian noise but it too has limits.

> If so any python or c++ implementation that can help?

The [pykalman package](https://pykalman.github.io/) would be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Esp for the pykalman package. I would like to put my problem in other way . How can I predict the a **Region** (say B in my picture), i.e radius and it's center point, where **most** of the objects seen on Region A have been moved to? I don't need to be precise. Even false positives are accepted.Now which concept do you recommend me to study. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would use a markov model of the whole problem.  Train it with empirical data that covers start and stop traffic, alternate routing, variable speed preferences, traffic lights, congestion, etc.

Comment: After some study. I see that Markov model is completly based on states. In my case I just have a randomId and positions ( I can estimate an approximate velocity and acceleration ). Can it be possible with markov model still? What I think it is more or less data association problem. Let me know what do you think? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A Kalman filter helps model the motion of a single object. The problem you have is that you don't know for certain which measurements (id,position) originate from which object, since they are allowed to change their ids. That makes this a tracking problem as well, where you'll need to estimate, for each object, the list of ids it has used in the past. The reason this matters is that it could take more than 15 minutes to get from Region A to Region B, and all the random-ids you receive from Region B don't match the ones you got from the object when it was in Region A.

There is a lot of work on these sorts of problems (see http://www.probabilistic-robotics.org/ for information).

I will attempt to describe a simple solution, but this is actually a deep topic with a lot of historical work. I'm describing a sort of variant of a Particle Filter here:

1. Keep a table of "Object" that will contain all historical information for the object (i.e., the car). This will store the historical list of (random-id, position) pairs you believe the object has used in reporting its position.
2. Each measurement you receive is (random-id, position, time). Decide which object it belongs to. How to decide? Well first, if the random-id exactly matches a previous one, and that id has been used for less than 15 minutes, then you can assign it exactly. Otherwise, you'll need to deal with cases where the random-id for the object has now changed. One obvious algorithm is to match it to object whose last measured position is closest. In general, your motion model (such as a Kalman filter) will determine how to do this correspondence assignment. Sometimes you'll have to decide that the measurement is in fact a *new* object that appeared out of nowhere, or from the edge of the map.
3. When you receive a measurement in Region B and have assigned it to an object, now check if any past measurement of that object was in Region A. That will tell if you have a situation of an object moving from Region A to Region B.

What I've described is essentially an online tracking algorithm with MAP estimation of correspondences, and a pluggable motion model. The algorithm will continuously maintain a list of "traces" of a each unique object.

Comment: Thanks a lot for understanding my problem. **check if any past measurement of that object was in Region A** . Since the Id of the object is changed by te time it reached Region B, It results trueNegative. If I can find the valid linkability of objects seen in Regions A (say at 12:00Pm) and in region B (say at 12:15) .Then my problem is solved right. ofcouse some times It might be falsepositive. Since I am designing an attacker model, It false positive helps the users by protecting their privacy. The main idea behind changing thier Id is to protect the user(object location) privacy.